# ElasticSearch cannot find an exact value that exists in a string field

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

When I do an empty query to list some results, I see the values are there. Ex:

```
{
    "took": 6,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3024,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5-j6uVuoyTMhX204",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail1029.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5-mTuVuoyTMhX205",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail1321.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5-xkuVuoyTMhX209",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail2567.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5zr8uVuoyTMhX20F",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail2122.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5z23uVuoyTMhX20L",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail1823.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5-53uVuoyTMhX21A",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail1616.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5_AXuVuoyTMhX21C",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail3002.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5_j3uVuoyTMhX21U",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail3039.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5_yQuVuoyTMhX21d",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail1136.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5zbquVuoyTMhX20C",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail166.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5zfsuVuoyTMhX20E",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail2767.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt59jQuVuoyTMhX20p",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail2852.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5_PpuVuoyTMhX21J",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail1392.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt58YguVuoyTMhX20N",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail603.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5_38uVuoyTMhX21h",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail416.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt5-JFuVuoyTMhX20y",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail896.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt6B1NuVuoyTMhX22i",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail846.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt6B3vuVuoyTMhX22k",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail1214.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt6B90uVuoyTMhX22o",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail1536.png"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "geotiff_test",
            "_type": "geometa",
            "_id": "AVtt6COkuVuoyTMhX22y",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "thumbnail": "thumbnail246.png"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Yet when I run a query like this, it returns nothing:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/geotiff_test/geometa/_search -d '{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail1536.png"
        }
    }
}'
```

This is the result:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

If this were Solr, all I want to do is run this simple query: `thumbnail:"thumbnail1536.png"`

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact term is not matching because your document field `thumbnail` got analyzed with `standard` analyzer and stored it as `thumbnail1536` and `png`.

In Elasticsearch there are different queries for `text` (**full-text**) and `keyword` (**exact-term**). The one you written comes under latter category.

If you run following `full-text` query you will get desired results:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/geotiff_test/geometa/_search -d '{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail1536.png"
        }
    }
}'
```

But as you are trying to search for `exact-term` using `term` queries are preferred.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/geotiff_test/geometa/_search -d '{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "thumbnail.keyword": "thumbnail1536.png"
        }
    }
}'
```

Note: Here `.keyword` is `keyword` version of `thumbnail` field.

Although both yield same results, the above query is more efficient than former one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your field is mapped/typed. Please refer to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) from the elastic search website.

Note that you could alter the mapping to better suit your needs.

Comment: I'm really new to ES. So I'm not sure why that even matters because in Solr, that query would work against either a string or a text field.